# how to retrieve page source of cross domain using javascript ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain

Hello i need to retrieve page source from **site1.com to site2.com**

I tried **file_getcontents of php** but my site is dynamic and unique for each users.

so i need to request page source using JAVASCRIPT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do it because of the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) unless the page and browser supports [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control).

Comment: Read through the document, it tells you what headers to look at.

Answer (score 2):

like epascarello said, you can't due to the same origin policy.  If you control both sites, you can use CORS to achieve it.

If you don't the best bet is to make requests to the domain you control, and have your server fetch what you need from the other url.  It's called proxying. It's not that difficult to do.

Comment: i cant do via server because...the other site contains dynamic values.that is unique for each users.

Comment: @JustinBiaber It does not matter what you need, security is security. It is there for a reason. Hackers also what to access your bank account since it is different for every user.

Comment: if you can do it via ajax, you can do it via a server call.